# What is a good open source B-tree implementation in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

I am looking for a lean and well constructed open source implementation of a B-tree library written in C. It needs to be under a non-GPL license so that it can be used in a commercial application. Ideally, this library supports the B-tree index to be stored/manipulated as a disk file so that large trees can be built using a configurable (ie: minimal) RAM footprint.

Note: Since there seemed to be some confusion, a Binary Tree and a B-Tree are *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out QDBM: http://fallabs.com/qdbm/.  It's LGPL (can be used in commercial app), implements a disk backed hash and/or B+ tree with arbitrary key/value pairs, and builds on a variety of platforms.

Comment: Nice! - This is a good addition to the list. Thanks!

Comment: On second thought, I think this should also be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 8):

The author of the [SQLite implementation](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/fileview?f=sqlite/src/btree.c&v=1.504) has disclaimed copyright.  If LGPL is okay, then maybe you could use [GNUpdate's implementation](http://gnupdate.cvs.sourceforge.net/gnupdate/libpackman/modules/database/gnupdate/db/btree.c?revision=1.12&view=markup)?

Comment: the GNUpdate one is a B+Tree

Answer (score 6):

If LGPL is ok, then [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/) might fit the bill.  LGPL allows linking with a non-Free application, without adding any constraints on the distribution of the final product.

Comment: It seems to have moved to http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/ .

Comment: Kyoto Cabinet  is a GPL follow up to Tokyo Cabinet but after using it a for a while it has some very bad habits, for example no exception handling so on std::bad_alloc the app crashs or undefined and unconstraint memory usage  patterns.

Answer (score 3):

[Attractive Chaos](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/programs/) implement kbtree.h. It's a efficient B-tree library

Answer (score 2):

I came across [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/WB) - The WB B-Tree Database for SCM, Java, C#, and C that's a GNU package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can considere the berkeley db. It is using a b-tree internally.